# Apply CSS Alpha overlay on image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply an alpha overlay on my image. Right now, it's applying across the whole body of the page, rather than just the image. Help?

http://jsfiddle.net/21ku3o7f/

```
<div class="dimmed">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>

.dimmed:after {
  content: " ";
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/21ku3o7f/1/

```
<div class="dimmed">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>

.dimmed {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.dimmed:after {
  content: " ";
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.dimmed img {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply css code

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
<div class="dimmed">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
</div>
```

```
.dimmed:after {
  content: " ";
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.dimmed{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dimmed img{vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/21ku3o7f/4/)**

**CSS:**

```
.dimmed:after {
    content:" ";
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

/* newly added code */

.dimmed { 
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```